# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsp

I am having difficulties while trying to launch my application, I looked for my mistake for a couple of days but i am stuck somewhere in the code and asking for your assistance... Thanks

Add Customer COntrller :

```
 package com.witlab.controller;

import com.witlab.services.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.witlab.services.CustomerService;
import com.witlab.customer.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Controller
public class AddCustomerController {

 @Autowired
CustomerService customerservice;

@RequestMapping(value="/AddCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addcustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
    return "AddCustomer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="InsertCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertCustomer(@ModelAttribute ("customer") Customer customer, ModelMap model)
    {                 System.out.println(customer.getAddress());
        if (customer!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(customer.getName());
            System.out.println(customer.getCity());
            System.out.println(customer.getPhone());
          System.out.println(model.addAttribute("Name", customer.getName()));


       model.addAttribute("Name", customer.getName());
        model.addAttribute("Address", customer.getAddress());
        model.addAttribute("city", customer.getCity());
        model.addAttribute("phone", customer.getPhone());
        model.addAttribute("mobile", customer.getMobile());
            customerservice.createCustomer(customer);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
        return "AddCustomer";
    }



}
```

dispatcher-servlet :

```
<context:annotation-config /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.witlab.controller" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />



      <bean id="CustomerDAO" class="com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate" />  
      <bean id="customerService" class="com.witlab.services.CustomerServiceImpl" />  
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" /> 

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:url="${jdbc.url}"
p:username="${jdbc.username}"
p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans>
```

Customer Service :

```
package com.witlab.services;

import com.witlab.customer.Customer;
import java.util.List;

public interface CustomerService {
public void createCustomer(Customer customer);
public Customer getCustomer(double Id);
public List<Customer> getCustomers();
public void deleteCustomer(double Id);
public void updateCustomer(double Id, String Name, String Address, String city, String phone, String mobile);

}
```

Customer JDBCTemplate :

```
package com.witlab.customer;

import java.util.List; 
import javax.sql.DataSource; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class CustomerJDBCTemplate implements CustomerDAO{

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;


private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateobj;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
{
    this.dataSource = dataSource; 
    this.jdbcTemplateobj = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
} 


 public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
     System.out.print("In Template"+customer.getName());
    String SQL="insert into customer (Name, Address,city, phone, mobile) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplateobj.update(SQL, new Object[]{customer.getName(),     customer.getAddress(),customer.getCity(), customer.getPhone(), customer.getMobile()});
    return;        
}

@Override
public Customer getCustomer(double Id) {
    String SQL="select * from customer where Id=?";
    Customer customer=jdbcTemplateobj.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{Id},new CustomerMapper());
    return customer;
}


public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    String SQL="select * from customer";
    List <Customer> customers=jdbcTemplateobj.query(SQL, new CustomerMapper());
    return  customers;
}

@Override
public void deleteCustomer(double Id) {
    String SQL="delete from customer where Id=?";
    jdbcTemplateobj.update(SQL, Id);
    return;
}


@Override
public void updateCustomer(double Id, String Name, String Address, String city, String phone, String mobile) {
    String SQL = "update customer set String = ?, String = ?, String = ?, String = ?, mobile = ? where Id = ?";
    jdbcTemplateobj.update(SQL, Name, Address, city, phone, mobile, Id);
    return;
}   

}
```

Error :

```
Feb 05, 2014 12:49:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Feb 05, 2014 12:49:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 05, 2014 12:50:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Feb 05, 2014 12:50:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 05, 2014 12:50:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Feb 05, 2014 12:50:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/WhizzyBilling] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate.createCustomer(CustomerJDBCTemplate.java:37)
    at com.witlab.services.CustomerServiceImpl.createCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.witlab.controller.AddCustomerController.insertCustomer(AddCustomerController.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Please add this line.  com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate.createCustomer(CustomerJDBCTemplate.java:37)

Comment: You haven't posted any useful code.  The most relevant lines from your exception are: `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate.createCustomer(CustomerJDBCTemplate.java:37) ` So try posting that.

Comment: Posted CustomerJDBCTemplate Class

Comment: Post the `CustomerServiceImpl` class as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining your `CustomerJDBCTemplate` bean like so

```
<bean id="CustomerDAO" class="com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate" />
```

In this case, there is no reason for the `setDataSource` method to be called. As such, the `jdbcTemplateObj` field will remain `null`.

There are a few ways to fix this.

Option 1: remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the `dataSource` field and add a `<property>` element to the `<bean>` definition like so

```
<bean id="CustomerDAO" class="com.witlab.customer.CustomerJDBCTemplate" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Spring will invoke your `setDataSource(..)` method, passing in the `dataSource` bean you've defined. This will initialize the `jdbcTemplateobj` field.

Option 2: Instead of the `setDataSource()` method, add a `@PostConstruct` method

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.jdbcTemplateobj = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

When Spring is done initializing your bean and injecting any fields, it will invoke this method, initializing the `jdbcTemplateobj` field.

Option 3: Remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the field and add it to the `setDataSource(..)` method.

Comment: I'm getting data from the form but I'm unable to Insert into database and getting error at  jdbcTemplateobj.update(SQL, new Object[]{customer.getName(), customer.getAddress(),customer.getCity(), customer.getPhone(), customer.getMobile()});

Comment: @SridhatTurupati An error that is related to your question or unrelated? What is your comment concerning? Did you make changes?

Comment: I didnot done any changes the error was realted to the question, the exception was raised when createCustomer method was called and at line jdbcTemplateobj.update

Comment: @SridhatTurupati A `NullPointerException` because `jdbcTemplateob` is `null`. Read my answer, it provides solutions.

Comment: @SridhatTurupati Consider upvoting useful answers and accepting answers that you feel answered the question best.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere where a variable could be `null` but shouldn't be, check it before using it.  That means, especially, check it before using the dot operator to access methods or member variables. You are already checking this for the variable `customer` but not for `model` or `customerservice`.

Comment: The exception is thrown inside `customerService.createCustomer()`.

Comment: Same principle applies.